# How do I dynamically create class objects in a loop?

Tags: c++

I need to create several different class objects. And there are too much of them to create them manually. So I have thought about something like a mutable object name but i recognized that this method wouldn't work. In my case I have a class (class Car). This class takes 6 parameters and now I have a loop which provides the parameters(the parameters are random and changed every time the loop passes). Because of the different parameters in each pass I need a new class object created every time the loop passes and somehow I don't know how to write the code to create and initialize these class objects dynamically.

Comment: Make a `std::vector<Car>` and `.push_back()` new objects into it.

Comment: If this is homework and you can't use the standard library you have to mention that. Remember that most of the people who answer do not have such restrictions. Instead they will show you the proper way in modern `c++`.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: @Josh.K Discussing everything on air is not considered as a good question asking manner in SO. You could also show your efforts in a minimal code, by which the community can help you more effectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an array:

```
int NUM_CARS = 6;
Car* cars[NUM_CARS];
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CARS; ++i) {
    cars[i] = new Car(getCarParamethers(i));
}
```

Comment: It is 2018 why would you suggest to make a raw array of raw pointers? Why not use this as an opportunity to show a novice developer some modern C++ idioms?

Comment: See also `std::vector` and `shared_ptr`.